# Usar conteudo selecionado pelo usuário no ComboBox como key (map) em classe enum

Tags: java, hashmap, jcombobox

Beleza, galera?
To com uma dificuldade. É exatamente o que o título diz.
**Código que contem o cbox:**

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File(pastaPadrao));
String[] siglaStrings = { "Selecione", "CIC", "CISEI", "GERMEM" };
public  JComboBox<String> siglaList = new JComboBox<String>(siglaStrings);
int teste;

public TelaInicial() {
    super("Selecionar um Caso de Uso para validação");
    this.setLocation(new Point(600, 400));
    Container container = getContentPane();
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    container.setLayout(layout);
    container.add(siglaList);

    JButton btnSelecionarCasoUso = new JButton("Selecionar Caso de Uso");

    btnSelecionarCasoUso.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            fc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));

            int res = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            teste = siglaList.getSelectedIndex();
            if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION && teste != 0) {
                File arquivo = fc.getSelectedFile();
                ResultadoQa resultadoQa = new ResultadoQa(arquivo.getName());
                resultadoQa.setVisible(true);
                resultadoQa.setSize(1200, 800);
                resultadoQa.setLocation(new Point(100, 50));
                resultadoQa.setResultado(getResultadoQa(arquivo));
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você não selecionou nenhum arquivo\n ou não selecionou a sigla do CSU.");
            }   
        }
    });

    container.add(btnSelecionarCasoUso);

    setSize(400, 200);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

**Classe enum com as chaves:**

```
public enum TipoItem {

/*Itens Genéricos*/
REGRA_NEGOCIO_GENERICA     ("Regra de Negócio Genérica", "(RNEG).(\\d+)"),
REGRA_VALIDACAO_GENERICA   ("Regra de Validação Genérica", "(RVAG).(\\d+)"),
FLUXO_ALTERNATIVO_GENERICA ("Fluxo Alternativo Genérico", "(FAG)(\\d+)"),
FLUXO_EXCECAO_GENERICA     ("Fluxo de Exceção Genérico", "(FEG)(\\d+)"),
MENSAGEM_GENERICA          ("Mensagem Genérica", "(MSGG).(\\d+)"),

SIGLA                      ("Sigla do CSU", "(siglaLista)"), //*** --> tem que ser recebido na tela inicial junto com a escolha do doc
REGRA_NEGOCIO              ("Regra de Negócio", "(RNE).(\\d+).(\\d+)"),
REGRA_VALIDACAO            ("Regra de Validação", "(RVA).(\\d+).(\\d+)"),
REQUISITO_FUNCIONAL        ("Requisito Funcional", "(RF).(\\d+)"),  
REQUISITO_NAO_FUNCIONAL    ("Requisito Não Funcional", "(RNF).(\\d+)"),
MENSAGEM                   ("Mensagem", "(MSG).(\\d+).(\\d+)"),
FLUXO_PRINCIPAL            ("Título do Fluxo Principal", "(Fluxo Principal)"),
FLUXO_ALTERNATIVO          ("Fluxo Alternativo", "(FA)(\\d+)"),
FLUXO_EXCECAO              ("Fluxo de Exceção", "(FE)(\\d+)"),
PONTO_INCLUSAO             ("Ponto de Inclusão", "(PI).(\\d+)"),
PONTO_EXTENSAO             ("Ponto de Extensão", "(PE).(\\d+)"),
ATOR                       ("Ator", "((A)|(a))(tor)(\\s)"),
COMPLEXIDADE               ("Complexidade", "((Baixa)|(Média)|(Alta))"),
PRIORIDADE                 ("Prioridade", "((Opcional)|(Desejavel)|(Essencial))"),

MSG_FE                     ("MSG dento do Fluxo de Exceção na respectiva oredem", "(O sistema exibe a MSG)"),

SAAA                       ("SAAA", "(SAAA)"),
INTERFACE                  ("Interface", "((I)|(i))(nterface)(\\s)"),
TERMOINGLES                ("Termos em Inglês", ""),
CAMPO                      ("Campos", "");


private final String descricao;
private final String expressaoRegular;

TipoItem(String descricao, String expressaoRegular){
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.expressaoRegular = expressaoRegular;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public String getExpressaoRegular() {
    return expressaoRegular;
}
```

}

Estou usando o HashMap para definir algumas keys, sendo assim,  o que eu quero é transformar a string do índice selecionado pelo usuário em uma key, assim o meu programa vai me retornar a quantidade de ocorrência dessa String no doc (word). Ou seja, eu só quero adicionar mais uma chave, só que é como se fosse um Scan, e não uma constante já definida na classe enum (onde estão as chaves). Agradeço muitão a quem tentar ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta o seguinte: primeiro, cria o *renderer:*

```
class TipoItemRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value != null) {
            TipoItem tipoItem = (TipoItem) value;

            if (index == -1) {
                setText("" + tipoItem.ordinal());
            } else {
                setText(tipoItem.getDescricao());
            }
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Então, instancia o *comboBox:*

```
comboBox = new JComboBox(TipoItem.values());
comboBox.addActionListener(this); // Vai chamar o método actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
comboBox.setRenderer(new TipoItemRenderer());
```

Por último, cria o método do evento:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
    TipoItem tipoItem = (TipoItem) comboBox.getSelectedItem();

    System.out.println(tipoItem.ordinal() + " - " + tipoItem.getDescricao());
}
```

Comment: Precisa de um comboboxmodel para isso funcionar. renderer sozinho presume-se de que um model esteja tratando o tipo de objeto TipoItem, sem ele, o renderer não receberá nunca um objeto tipoitem.

Comment: Não tive como testar, mas com essa resposta você deve chegar onde precisa.

Comment: Não fui eu o autor dá pergunta. Foi só uma dica pra completar a resposta, pq somente com renderer não vai funcionar, precisa de Combomodel também.